# Can't Compile in NTFS Partition

Tags: compiling, ntfs

I want to compile  a source code in a NTFS  partiotion but can not as shown in the following picture:

[image: can not be compiled in NTFS partitions]

Although i can write files into that partition but Compile NOT!

How can i solve it?

Comment: Can you post the error message you got?

Comment: @EricCarvalho i add a pic, see it!

Comment: I think you could run `bash configure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not compile because your file does not has executable permission. And you can not set file permission which is in ntfs partition because you did not mount your partition with write permission(But you can copy, cut, paste file). Easy solution is use ntfs-config

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-config
sudo ntfs-config
```

Enable write permission for Internal and External device

[image]

Or you can set your fstab manually(ntfs-config just set your fstab). Your fstab should look like this..

```
#Entry for /dev/sda5 :
UUID=7818C41F18C3DA70   /media/Local    ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0
#Entry for /dev/sda6 :
UUID=7ED0CAEED0CAABA9   /media/Office   ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0
```

Comment: He said he can write to the ntfs partition.

Comment: @EricCarvalho you missed, i also said he can copy, cut and paste but can not change file permission

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea using a NTFS partition to compile source code because usually the compiling generates executable files, which need the `execute` file permission, not provided by NTFS.

Comment: I just compiled a c program on my NTFS partition and ran the executable without any problem.  I don't think it is correct to say NTFS does not provide execute file permission. Maybe the problem is in the mounting option.

Comment: NTFS does **not** support execution of linux executable files. You can't even mark the files as executable.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use permissions options which will let you change permissions of your indiviual file thus making it possible to be executed. If you mount the ntfs partition with the permissions option, then chmod / chown will work

```
/dev/sda2   /mnt/excess ntfs-3g    permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    0   0
```

You can then

```
sudo chown your_user:your_user /mnt/excess
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very relevant https://askubuntu.com/a/208349/11212
adding
 `someWeirdId  /media/name  ntfs  auto,stuff,stuff,stuff,**uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000**  0  0`