# Cannot create files except in home partition

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, permissions, filesystem, files

On my system I have made 3 partitions except home partition but Ubuntu doesn't let me create or delete any files on those partitions. Even copy and paste options are not available. Using my poor knowledge I made some file using terminal but I don't know how to add files to those partitions.

Please anybody help me. I'm new to Ubuntu. My experience with Ubuntu is only two weeks.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to authenticate to an IRC network - disable IRC if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It might be because you *do not have the permissions to use* those partitions.

- To take ownership of a drive or partition (internal and external), simply run the following command:

  ```
  sudo chown -R username:username /partition/mount-point
  ```

  Where **username** is your actual username, **mount-point** is the directory in the file system to which the partition will be mounted *and not* the device name (eg: /dev/sda1).
- **To determine the mount-point**, run `mount` in the terminal, and locate the line that corresponds to the drive or partition.

  - If you have not set a label for the partition, it will look something like this:

    ```
    /dev/sda5 on /media/7e3fbc57-03fe-4742-bb72-756f31852059
    ```
  - If you have set the label with something descriptive, it should look like this:

    ```
    /dev/sda5 on /media/data
    ```

  Based on the example, the mount-point will be something like `/media/7e3fbc57-03fe-4742-bb72-756f31852059` OR `/media/data`.

  Now, all you need to do now is run the command below with your **username** and the correct **mount-point**:

  ```
  sudo chown -R peachy:peachy /media/7e3fbc57-03fe-4742-bb72-756f31852059
  ```

  OR

  ```
  sudo chown -R peachy:peachy /media/data
  ```

  **Note**: Your username and mount-point will be different. Also, if you have set a label that contains spaces (e.g. 1TB External or My Files), you will need to enclose the entire mount-point path in single quotes, such as:

  ```
  sudo chown -R peachy:peachy '/media/My Files'
  ```

  OR

  ```
  sudo chown -R peachy:peachy '/media/1TB External'
  ```

#### You are now the owner of the partition and should be able to do whatever you want with the drive or partition.

**To change ownership of NTFS partitions, see:**

- [How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)
- [How to 'chown' on an NTFS ( or FAT32 ) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208318/how-to-chown-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. Now I fixed my problem using your advises. those instructions are very clear to understand. Thank you again and again

Answer (score 0):

There might be several reasons for this problem.

Maybe the partitions are mounted read-only, which is the default for NTFS partitions as far as I remember. If you're using NTFS, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions for how to mount them read-write.
For other file systems you can have a look inside the file /etc/fstab. Documentation about how entries in this file should look like could be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab. But be careful if you modify this file, you might loose access to your filesystems completely.

Another reason could be that you're not granted the rights modify files on the partition. Open the partition in Nautilus file manager and choose File -> Properties -> Permissions. If this folder is not owned by you or your group, change the ownership or give 'others' write permissions.